# how can i set time in angularjs as [ 2 min ago ] if [difference is 2 min from current time]?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am trying to set a time as for example , i have time as **[ 01:25:00 ]** then if now current time is **[ 01:28:00 ]** . It should show as "**3 min ago**". how can i do using angular and ionic.

i am trying some thing like :

1 min ago , 2 min ago , 30 min ago , 1 hour ago

my html code:

```
      <div class="item item-divider item-input-wrapper">
             <p>Time : {{ messages.MSGTIME | date:'shortTime'}} </p>
      </div>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have a look on moment.js. You can easily write your own filter with this library.

Comment: No im not using moment.js in my ionic, is there any method in angular?

Comment: Then, why do you accept an answer which requires moment.js ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to use moment.js (what I would recommend) you can write your own date filter. A simple example (http://plnkr.co/edit/BVH5Q3?p=preview):

```
angular.module('app').filter('myDate', myDate);

function myDate() {
    var s = 1000;
    var m = s * 60;
    var h = m * 60;
    return function(date) {
        var d = date.getTime() - Date.now();
        if (d > h)
            return '' + d / h + ' hours ago';
        if (d > m)
            return '' + d / m + ' minutes ago';
        if (d > s)
            return '' + d / s + ' seconds ago';
        return '' + d + ' ms ago';;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [angular-moment](https://github.com/urish/angular-moment) , filter `amDifference` can fullfill your purpose. You cna use it like this :

```
 <p>Time : {{ messages.MSGTIME | amDifference : null : 'hours'}} </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm in a hurry right now, but here  something from the top of my head for a q'n'd approach:

- Create own filter
- split(":") both time strings
- calc difference of hours and minutes
- then:

  ```
  ret = (diffHours > 0)? diffHours + " hours and " : "";
  ret += diffMinutes + " minutes ago";
  return ret;
  ```